# MVC: Simplest way to create a link to the application base URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a page where I want to include a "Home" link which takes me to my application's base URL.  So far the simplest way I managed to achieve this is through the following line of Razor code, but it's not pretty and I'm not terribly confident about it:

```
@Html.RouteLink(MyResources.HomeLinkLabel, new { controller = "" })
```

Note that if I don't include `controller = ""` then the hyperlink it generates takes me to the current page, not my base URL.

I feel I'm missing something obvious... What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The reason the empty controller works is because the RouteLink uses the specified routes and the default is usually the HomeController.Index method which is why it works. You can feel confident that it will return the correct url as long as you don't have another route that takes precedence (which would mean anything not specifying a specific controller/home in the url would go there anyway)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the following code to get the root URL

```
Url.Content("~/");
```

The server-side `~/` syntax references the root of your application (meaning it will take into account if your app is registered in a virtual path in IIS).

Comment: Agree with this.  Alternatively you can use `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")` if you always want to refer to it by controller/action.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go to the an specific action, you could just include the controller name and the action you want to go:

```
@Html.RouteLink(MyResources.HomeLinkLabel, new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" })
```

Now, if you want to go to the root, you can just put something like

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/")">...</a>
```

Comment: Just a note that the `<a>` tag above is just wrong since if the application base url is a virtual path then `/` will take you to the root of the site rather than the application base url.

Comment: Thanks! I want to avoid specifying a controller and action, so the Url.Content is perfect. I accepted @maricind's response as it's short and to the point but +1'ed yours.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just write regular ol' HTML:

```
<a href="/">@MyResources.HomeLinkLabel</a>
```

Comment: This is not compatible with virtual directories, since the `/` is relative to the host. If your app is in a virtual directory, the link would take you to the root site rather than the root of the application.